# Works council approval Germany

Tags: working-visas, germany, blue-card

Did anyone here need approval from a works council after receiving a job offer? How long did it take? In my case, after 3 rounds of interviews I was offered the position and after accepting it, the HR lady said I now have to wait for works council approval to start the visa / blue card process.

Comment: The person to ask is that lady.... She'll know better than random strangers on the internet.

Comment: Which country are you hoping to work in?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I’m talking about Germany. 
Jan, if she knew it she would tell me. If you don’t know it just ignore it. Thanks!

Comment: For hiring and firings the work councils (Betriebsrat)  must be consulted. They have a veto right if they believe that any conditions exsits that go against your interests. They normally meet when needed, hiring being a reason to do so soon.

Comment: For me the approval took 10 business days.

Comment: I have received a notification from HR that they are awaiting for work council approval and meeting supposed to happen on last Thursday. After that today 1 week completed and I have not received any response from them. is it normal?

Comment: did you finally get your contract? I have now the exact situation , how long does it takes

Comment: I am also having the same condition now can anybody tell how much is the time duration these days for work council to approve the job contract.

Comment: @stranger Nobody can give a general answer since nobody know how often the work council (Betriebsrat) meets at a specific location. Most members are employees that perform their normal jobs and meet only when needed.

Answer (score 2):

The worker council can object to *any* new hire (so it's not you specifically) under certain circumstances.

The law in question is [BetrVG §99](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/betrvg/__99.html)

> (3) Verweigert der Betriebsrat seine Zustimmung, so hat er dies unter Angabe von Gründen innerhalb einer Woche nach Unterrichtung durch den Arbeitgeber diesem schriftlich mitzuteilen. Teilt der Betriebsrat dem Arbeitgeber die Verweigerung seiner Zustimmung nicht innerhalb der Frist schriftlich mit, so gilt die Zustimmung als erteilt.

The workers council has **one week** to object in writing, *once informed*. If they don't, this counts as them having agreed.

We don't know how quickly the wheels turn in that specific company, for example if it is a big company, they may want to batch this and send all new candidates to the workers council together as one package once a week, and then have them object or not to each new hire by the time they send the next batch, instead of  sending them piecemeal keeping every single date and deadline for every single hire on file.

I would say that 10-15 business days until you hear from them is probably normal, especially since the workers council and employer are at odds most of the time, so they are in no hurry to cooperate. But if they are very well organized and work well with their workers council, 2 days would also be possible. Those laws describe maximum constraints, not minimum time if everyone agrees.